# How to automatically fill data in Excel in a blank cell, using a logical copy of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have data in cells A1-A50 and also data in C1-C50. 
Columns `A` and `C` are synchronized;
i.e., the value in `Cn` corresponds
to the value in `An`.

When I enter information in column A (new row, A51+) I want Excel to automatically fill in data for column C if what I entered in column A is also present above, using the corresponding data from C for that row.

Example:

```
  A      B      C
John          blueberry
Phil          apple
David         banana
John
David
```

I want Excel to fill in "blueberry" and "banana" in column C for the last two rows.

Comment: Your question is little confusing basically `John Blue`, `Phil Red` indicates Conditional Formatting but  **i want excel to 'see' that this information is the same as any of the row A1-A51, and to automatically fulfill it in column C**  is quite different !!

Comment: Your question is really unclear. I have proposed an edit, please approve it if I got your question right.

Answer (score 2):

Paste below formula:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$3,MATCH($A4,$A$1:$A$3,0))
```

to cell C4, then copy for the rest of list

Answer (score 1):

Paste this formula into the first empty cell in column C (in this case, at row 4):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A4;A$1:A3;0));VLOOKUP(A4;A$1:B3;3;FALSE))
```

(Modify "A4" in case you are on a different row).

Drag down to fill the empty cells below. 
It returns FALSE if there's no matching value in A.

Comment: But this will just display blanks and `FALSE` cells. The OP wants to see corresponding *values* from Column ``C``.

Comment: You're right - I edited the formula to account for C and not B.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it Works:**

1. Write this formula in Cell `B7` & fill down.

   `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A7,A3:B5,2,FALSE),"No Match")`
2. You get `Scenario Before New Data`.
3. Now enter desire Name in `A7` and after.
4. Finally you get `Scenario After New Data`.

**Note:**

1. Adjust the cell references in formula as
   needed.
2. You may replace text `No Match` in formula
   with any text of your choice or keep it blank.

Comment: what is wrong with this answer ?? **Since filling  "blueberry" and "banana" in column C for the last two rows, as OP says !!**